# what is the difference between axes.patch.set... and axes.set... in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just learn how to use matplotlib in python.I want to know the diffence of plot set use or not use 'patch'.I have tried the bellow code ,from the pics they seem no differences.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1=plt.figure(dpi=500,figsize=(10,10))
sub=fig1.add_subplot(2,2,1)
sub.patch.set_facecolor('green')
plt.show()
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1=plt.figure(dpi=500,figsize=(10,10))
sub=fig1.add_subplot(2,2,1)
sub.set_facecolor('green')
plt.show()
```

I have searched google but i find some people use patch while others not ,they don't why.
I want to know the difference and how to use both forms.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. `Axes.set_facecolor` gives you a *shortcut* to `Axes.patch.set_facecolor`:

From [matplotlib/axes/_base.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.2/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1503-L1513):

```
    def set_facecolor(self, color):
        """
        Set the facecolor of the Axes.


        Parameters
        ----------
        color : color
        """
        self._facecolor = color
        self.stale = True
        return self.patch.set_facecolor(color)
```

Note: `Axes` is an `Artist` subclass

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_facecolor.html), click on the `[source]` button.